# How to measure the two-point function for two phase media?

Tags: material-science

Given some two phase media, consisting of a random mixture of materials A and B. how does one measure the two-point function?

The one-point function is trivial to determine and can be done simply by randomly sampling a single point. The faction of times it falls in material A to the total number of samples gives the one-point function (or volume fraction).

What about the two-point function?

Comment: Calculating the "two-point function" (i.e., correlation function?) should be trivial if you know what the spatial distribution of A and B are. You're asking how to calculate the correlation function or you're asking how to determine the distribution of A and B?